# Installing easy_install... to get to installing lxml

Tags: python, lxml, easy-install

I've come to grips with the fact that ElementTree isn't going to do what I want it to do. I've checked out the documentation for lxml, and it appears that it will serve my purposes. To get lxml, I need to get easy_install. So I downloaded it from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other), and put it in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`. Then I went to that folder, and ran `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg`.

That installed successfully. Then I got excited because I thought the whole point of easy_install was that I could then just install via easy_install lxml, and lxml would magically get downloaded, built, and installed properly, ready for my importing enjoyment. So I ran `easy_install lxml`. I pasted the results below. What should I do?

```
easy_install lxml
Searching for lxml
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/lxml/
Reading http://codespeak.net/lxml
Best match: lxml 2.2.6
Downloading http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxml-2.2.6.tgz
Processing lxml-2.2.6.tgz
Running lxml-2.2.6/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/49/49N0+g5QFKCm51AbzMtghE+++TI/-Tmp-/easy_install-rxbP6K/lxml-2.2.6/egg-dist-tmp-fjakR0
Building lxml version 2.2.6.
NOTE: Trying to build without Cython, pre-generated 'src/lxml/lxml.etree.c' needs to be available.
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.12
Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib
unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: (re: your code editor troubles) Indent by four spaces to make a code block, or click the "01010" button in the editor while you have some things highlighted.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First off we don't use easy_install anymore. We use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/). Please use pip instead.

To get to your particular troubles, as the comments point out, you're missing GCC. On OS X, [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/) Command Line Tools provides GCC, as well as many other programs necessary for building software on OS X. For OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) and newer, either install Xcode through the App Store, or alternatively, install only the Xcode Command Line Tools with

```
xcode-select --install
```

For more details, please see the [Apple Developer FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-DOWNLOADING_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_IS_NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_XCODE_FOR_OS_X_10_9__HOW_CAN_I_INSTALL_THEM_ON_MY_MACHINE_) or search the web for "install Xcode Command Line Tools".

For older versions of OS X, you can get Xcode Command Line Tools from the [downloads page of the Apple Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (free registration required).

Once you have GCC installed, you may still encounter errors during compilation if the C/C++ library dependencies are not installed on your system. On OS X, the [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) project is the easiest way to install and manage such dependencies. Follow the instructions on the Homebrew website to install Homebrew on your system, then issue

```
brew update
brew install libxml2 libxslt
```

Possibly causing further trouble in your case, you placed the downloaded setuptools in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`. Please do not download any files to this location. Instead, I suggest you download the file to your home directory, or your usual `Downloads` directory. After downloading it, you're supposed to run `sh setuptools-X.Y.Z.egg`, which will then install it properly into the appropriate `site-packages` and put the executable `easy_install` on your path.

Comment: +1 for pointing out we should be using pip.  I had no idea.  It's nice when packages just work.

Answer (score 13):

Ensure you have libxml2-dev and libxslt1-dev installed

```
apt-get install libxml2-dev
apt-get install libxslt1-dev
```

Then your installation should build properly.

Answer (score 10):

try:
`sudo apt-get install python-lxml`

Comment: For Python3 use "apt-get install python3-lxml"

Comment: Better to use pip. It will give you a more recent version than your package maintainer. Sooner or later you'll be glad you used it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `lxml` wants to build an extension that requires access to a C compiler. You will need `gcc` for that. Try running `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and that should fix this particular issue.

Comment: What OS/distribution is this on?

Comment: @John The better command for Debain/Ubuntu is `sudo apt-get install build-essential` because it includes tools like make and a few other friends that are usually used in concert with gcc/g++.

Comment: Ah. OSX doesn't install the gcc compiler. Get Homebrew (http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) or its less-intelligent cousin, `ports`, and then install gcc through them instead. Most of your pain is happening because there isn't an official, sensible packager on OS X. Sorry. =/

Comment: @gotgenes » You are right. Thank you for the correction; I've updated accordingly.

Comment: I tried to mkdir homebrew in /usr/local, but it permission denied me. Usually it just asks for my password.

Comment: OSX 10.5 is bundled with 2.5.1....Perhaps there is a conflict between the two versions....Did you install your own copy of Python 2.6? Might be a PATH issue...

Comment: Yes. I installed Python 2.6. I don't understand what that has to do with getting permission denied when trying to mkdir homebrew from /usr/local.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that all the following packages are installed on your system first:

```
gcc gcc-c++ python-devel libxml2 libxml2-dev libxslt libxslt-dev
```

You should be able to install them using some variant of:
sudo apt-get install 
sudo yum install

Only after all of the above have been successfully installed should you attempt to run:

```
sudo pip install lxml
```