# sgml parsing in python3.1

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to port feedparser over to Python3.1 and I realized that sgmllib had been deprecated from Python2.7 upward and subsequently removed. Which alternatives would you suggest I use in Python3.1 to perform analogous tasks?

Answer (score 3):

use [`lxml`](http://codespeak.net/lxml/parsing.html), it is very efficient as it is written in `c`, another popular HTML parser is there `BeautifulSoup` but again it is based on sgmllib so i would recommend that you should go for `lxml`.

Comment: I was considering lxml too, but I was hoping sgmllib would have been moved over as a submodule in the stdlib.

Comment: there is a port exist though sgmllib3k but it is not maintained! check this link! http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Libraries/sgmllib3k-59523.shtml

Comment: Be warned that lxml can have some horrible dependencies.  See my lxml note here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368008/installing-easy-install-to-get-to-installing-lxml/4233083#4233083